# Passing commandline arguments to MsiPackage

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, burn, windows-installer

The Visual Studio Installer technology creates a bootstrapper which can take arguments (eg: /q) and pass it to the Msi.

I have a custom bootstrapper in WiX which has some ExePackages and one MsiPackages.

When I pass the argument in WiX to the custom bootstrapper the custom UI is shown.

**How can I pass the argument directly to the MsiPackage assuming the ExePackages are already installed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if I understand your question properly, but anyways in the default bootstrapper this is how we pass the arguments from command line:

```
<Wix>
  <Bundle> 
    <Variable Name="CommandLineArgument" bal:Overridable="yes"/>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage>
        <MsiProperty Name="CommandLineArgument" Value="[CommandLineArgument]"/>
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Make a note of the BAL:Overridable. That's how I was able to make sure that we can pass the property value from command line.

Comment: Don't forget to add the namespace declaration to the Wix element `xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"`, and link to the WixBalExtension.dll.